# Why the given expression takes so long in IRB

Tags: ruby, irb

Any idea why the following simple expression lasts so long in IRB:

```
irb(main):003:0> res='a'*(10**6)
```

It runs several minutes before finishes.

Whereas suppling the same expression to puts method f.E. is instanteous:

```
irb(main):003:0> puts('a'*(10**6))
```

Comment: The first example for me is instantaneous, too. As is the second.

Comment: Both have the same speed for me as well. I think this must be something about your particular setup.

Comment: @Mark: You're using 1.9 perhaps? I can see the speed difference using 1.8.7.

Comment: Yes, I am using 1.9. I didn't think to try on 1.8.7.

Comment: I see the time difference in 1.9.2-p0 as well as 1.8.7-p248, what OS are you using?

Comment: irb(main):002:0> IRB::version
=> "irb 0.9.6(09/06/30)"
irb(main):003:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.9.2"  (running on Linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out it's caused by Wirb module loaded from .irbrc startup file.
By commenting it out both examples now run comparable fast.